# Getting FuelPHP observers to use MySQL datetimes

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, fuelphp

I was trying to get the FuelPHP ORM Observers to use MySQL datetimes rather than unix timestamps, however I can't figure out how to use the code provided in the docs.

They provide this code:
Orm\Observer_CreatedAt::$mysql_timestamp = true;

But where do I use this? In the model? It doesn't seem to work there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something that was put in a bit hacky and should have been a config value from the beginning, something we'll fix for 1.1.

Best way to do it right now is probably to give the models using the CreatedAt/UpdatedAt observers an `_init()` method like the code below. The init method is called by the autoloader after loading the class.

```
public static function _init()
{
    Orm\Observer_CreatedAt::$mysql_timestamp = true;
    Orm\Observer_UpdatedAt::$mysql_timestamp = true;
}
```

Btw asking a question on our forums or on IRC will probably get you faster answers.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! BTW, I did ask on the forums as well. I posted both questions at the same time haha. I was sure to copy this answer over to the forums as well. Thanks again!